# How do I add an item from a class to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, static

I know the question seems weird, but I'll try to explain it the best that I can.  I am doing an Amusement Park Project where you have methods for the tickets, merchandise, etc.  I made a Ticket class with the methods, but now I'm in the AmusementPark class trying to create a method of taking the date from that class and putting it into a new ArrayList.   Maybe my code will help explain it.

First, here is my Ticket class......

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class Ticket {
    private long number;
    private String category; 
    private String holder;
    private String date;
    private double price;
    private boolean purchased;
    Ticket(long num, String cat, String h, String dt, double pr, boolean pch){
        this.number= num;
        this.category= cat;
        this.holder= h;
        this.date= dt;
        this.price= pr;
        this.purchased= pch;

    }
    long getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
    String getCategory(){
        return category;
    }
    String getHolder(){
        return holder;
    }
     String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    boolean getPurchased(){
        return purchased;
    }
    double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    void setPrice(double pr){
        price= pr;
    }
    void setChangePurchased(boolean newStatus){
        purchased= newStatus;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        DecimalFormat dm= new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        String disp;
        disp = "Number: " + getNumber() + "\nCategory: " + getCategory() + "\nTicket Holder Name: " + getHolder() + "\nDate: " + getDate()
        + "\nPrice: " + dm.format(getPrice()) + "\nPuchased Completed?: " + purchased;
        return disp;
    }
    }
```

Here is some of the Pseudo Code explaining what I am trying to do with the next class I'm about to post.

```
Create an ArrayList from the Ticket class.
 //The ticket class has the following constructors....
 // (Ticket number of type long, category of type String, Ticket holder of type String, Date of admission, purchase price of type double, variable named "purchased" whether the ticket has been paid for of type boolean)

 //One of the variables of type class is tickets in which the ticket class is made into an ArrayList. 
 //The next task is to get tickets for dates where they are available, which is done by searching tickets where the purchase is not completed. 

 Create a public ArrayList<Date> method called getTicketDates(){
    Create a variable called theDateArray which is a new ArrayList<Date>;
    For(starting at the first position of the list, go through the the entire list incrementing by one){
      if (boolean purchased of the Ticket ArrayList is false)**{
        Add the date of the object from the Ticket ArrayList to theDateArray ArrayList.}**    //This stores the dates of all tickets not yet purchased into the new ArrayList.  
    }
      Return theDateArray;
 }
   //The next task is to search through theDateArray for only select dates and post the available tickets for that date as an integer.  

  Create a method which displays the number of tickets for a specified date by going through theDateArray (Date date) {
     For(starting at the first position of theDateArray, go through the entire list and look for tickets that have a particular date){
        if (the date== entered date){
        Include the ticket as one of the tickets available for that date. 
        }

 }
     Return the total number of tickets available for that date as a type integer.  
 }
```

Okay, now here is my AmusementPark class.  *Note*  It is not finished.  I'm just trying to get this one part done....

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class AmusementPark {
    private ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;
    private ArrayList<Merchandise> merchandise;
    private String name;
    AmusementPark(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
        this.merchandise= new ArrayList<Merchandise>();
    }
    String getName(){
        return name;



    }
     public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
        ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();
        int i;
        String date = Ticket.getDate();    //This is not working.  See Reason Below.

        for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
            if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false){
                theDateArray.add(date);
            }

        }return theDateArray;
    }
    }
```

Okay, so now what happens when I try to call the method of getDate() from the Ticket class, it's not allowing me to use it for the reason that I cannot make a static reference to a non-static method.  However, when I try to make the method static, it messes up the other class by saying I cannot make a static reference to a non-static field.

An ArrayList of the Ticket class has already been made.  I need it to scroll through that list, get the ones where the boolean is false, and add the date to the next ArrayList.

Does this at all make sense?

Any ideas that would be better?

Comment: You need to call `getDate` for each instance if `Ticket` in the list you iterate. so `theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate()))` Because you want the date for a specific instance. By the way, this question is way to long, you should be able to explain that you can't call a method to get a value because it is not static. See [mcve]

Comment: DONT MAKE STATIC REFRENCE !!Make an object of class and your set methods cutting value to that object and now pass the object in arraylist .Each item of arraylist will  refer to object and Each object will have values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your method.

```
public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
    ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();
    int i;
    String date = Ticket.getDate();    //This is not working.  See Reason Below.

    for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
        if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false){
            theDateArray.add(date);
        }

    }
    return theDateArray;
}
```

Notice the problem on the `Ticket.getDate()` that you try to do whithout an instance, so a static call. But what you explain, you want the date for the `Ticket` of the list `tickets`. Good, you are iterating it after but are pushing this strange value `date` coming from a "static method".

You problem is that the instance holding the `date` you want is in the list. You are using it to see if it is purchased or not. So call the method on those instance to get the value :

```
for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
    if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false){
        theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
    }

}
```

But better :

```
Ticket ticket;
for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
    ticket = tickets.get(i);
    if(ticket.getPurchased()== false){
        theDateArray.add(ticket.getDate());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly what is required here is to extract dates for not purchased tickets into separate dates array. And you already got it correctly in your pseudocode, you just need to follow it more strictly during implementation:

```
public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates() {
    ArrayList<String> theDateArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate over all tickets
    for ( Ticket ticket : tickets ) {
        // if ticket not purchased
        if ( ! ticket.getPurchased() ) {
            // add ticket's date into array
            theDateArray.add( ticket.getDate() );
        }
    }
    return theDateArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DON'T MAKE STATIC REFERENCE !Instead of writing a what's code answer let's focus on the workaround of problem.
    Whenver you will set values to instance variables of TICKET Class it will refer to a particular object (new ticket()) to access its values if you make variables of class staticValues will be stored when class is loaded and not when object is created but arraylist items need to have
                Object of ticket Class.

A simple approach should be
                 ASSIGN  THE VALUES TO VARIABLES WHEN EVER YOU MAKE AN OBJECT OF TICKET CLASS BY BY PASSING VALUES IN ITS CONSTRUCTOR AND THEN 
                ADD THOSE OBJECTS TO ARRAYLISTITEMS

```
   ticket class

public class Ticket {
private long number;
private String category; 
private String holder;
private String date;
private double price;
private boolean purchased;
Ticket(long num, String cat, String h, String dt, double pr, boolean pch){
    this.number= num;
    this.category= cat;
    this.holder= h;
    this.date= dt;
    this.price= pr;
    this.purchased= pch;

}
 make a new object and pass values
   Ticket t1=new Ticket(3,"yourstring","yourstring",yourDouble,true/false);
```

add items in arrayliSt:

```
    List<Tickets> tList=new ArrayList();
               tList.add(t1);
              tList.add(t2);
               //and so on

 now retrive values from arralylist 
            Ticket t=tlist.get(0);
            t.cat;
            t.whatevrbe thevalue be
```